# how to iterate through json key,values in multiple dictionaries in python

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary

i am trying to compare keys of different dictionaries stored in json.if keys are same then store those keys in another dictionary but i am not getting the required output. input looks like:

```
  [  
   {  
      "huma":10,
      "sana":25
   },
   {  
      "sara":12,
      "huma":20,
      "      zeb:15
   }
]
```

what i tried is:

```
def compare():
    result_dictionary = {}
    with open('data.json') as data_file:    
        data = json.load(data_file)
        for d1 in data:
            for key, value in d1.items():
                print("key: {key} | value: {value}".format(key=key, value=value))
compare()
```

i am confused how to compare these keys of multiple dictionaries and key which matches store them in a new dictionary? the output should be "Huma"because only that is equal in both dictionaries.

Comment: is your input data only 2 dictionaries? or maybe more ? what if there are 3 dictionaries, should your key be in all 3 before you store it in another dictionary ? what if there are 83 dictionaries, should the key be in all 83 ? or should the key be in a majority of dictionaries, or minority as long as it is >1 ? -- please update your question with more information... Also please show us your code on how you "store in a dictionary" or "compare keys", as your current code just does some printing.

Comment: `import operator, functools` then `common_keys = functools.reduce(operator.and_, (d.keys() for d in data))` would produce a set of all common keys in a sequence of dictionaries.

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo it is not important that key should be in all dictionaries but if any of key match with any other key in a dictionary 1 or more time then it should be stored in another dictionary or in another list . right now i am just trying to get the common keys.

Comment: @user3778289 in that case you have a good answer already

Answer (score 3):

Using `collections`

**Demo:**

```
import collections
d = [{  "huma":10,"sana":25}, { "sara":12,"huma":20,"zeb":15}]
dd = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in d:
    for k,v in i.items():
        dd[k].append(v)
print([k for k,v in dd.items() if len(v) > 1])
```

**Output:**

```
['huma']
```